# 角/毛 (10 cents) for money: why?

Tags: etymology, expressions

from: [List of historical Chinese currency terms](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/list-of-historical-chinese-currency-terms/5404#5404)

> 角 (litterally a corner / a horn of an animal) = 毛 (litterally "a feather of a bird") = 1/10 the main unit.

Why use 角 and 毛 for, *what we might call in American English*, 10-cents?

Comment: Are you asking about the evolution of the word or how 1/10th of a dollar represents 10 cents.

Comment: I'm asking why 角字 and 毛字 are used to represent 1/10th of a 元.

Comment: I've never used 角 in oral communication. It's always 毛.
角 is usually used in written though. both 角and 毛 mean 10 cents

Comment: That's not true. I always use 角. Both are correct, and that isn't what the question is asking for.

Comment: You've generalised an individual preference into a language-wide feature. This is simply a bad linguistic practice. In addition, you didn't really answer the question.

Comment: 说的也对, 但是为啥这么多 downvote ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

角 came from 銀角, which was historically a currency that represented a fraction of the silver coin (銀元). 元 came from 圓, a description of the coin's circular shape. A theory for 角's use is that since the basic meaning of 角 is a horn; by extension it came to be used to describe "things that looks like horns". And from there, "corners" 角落, "angles" 角度, etc. Dividing a circle up like pizza slices creates a "角"; hence, the divisions of one 元 (圓) came to be called a 角.

As Carmelos said, 毛 came from a simplification of 毫 - it is the bottom radical of the latter. 毫 in turn comes from one of the traditional Chinese unit for small numbers: 分 厘 毫 絲, corresponding to the modern 10<sup>-3</sup> (it is still used for millimetres, 毫米/公厘). A theory is that 毛钱 was a type of coinage in the Song dynasty that had very small values, as its name suggests. The term persisted in that meaning of a "small denomination coin", and thus became synonymous with the modern small 角 coins.

Comment: I thought it might be relevant to note that in Cantonese, 毫 is still used as the colloquial term for 10 cents.

Comment: @Claw However, in Mandarin Chinese, 1 元 = 10 角 = 100 分 = 1000 厘 = 10000 毫

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how good you are at Chinese, 
you can read this Chinese wikipedia page for more information:
[http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/角_(貨幣)](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A7%92_%28%E8%B2%A8%E5%B9%A3%29)

"毛" is simplified from "毫", which means little amount.
In Chinese we have a saying as "一分一毫", which means very little amount.
In most part of China, "毛" and "角" are interchangeable.